# itextsharp adding footer text but its partially visible (C#.NET)

Tags: c#, itext

I've been using itextsharp SDK, I have a pdf file that has some data, I want to add header or footer text, it's adding it, but at the very end of the page, the header/footer text is partially visible

Please see the sample code:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("C:\Source pdf file.pdf");
string f_textPrefix = "Page No : 1";
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(reader, memoryStream);
    bool flag = false;
    for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
    {
        iTextSharp.text.Rectangle pageSize = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i);
        PdfContentByte pdfPageContents = pdfStamper.GetOverContent(i);
        pdfPageContents.BeginText();
        BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD,
                                                            BaseFont.CP1252,
                                                            false);                        
        System.Drawing.Color m_Color = new System.Drawing.Color();
        pdfPageContents.SetFontAndSize(baseFont, Convert.ToInt32(p_objParam.pdfBatesDetail.FontSize));
        pdfPageContents.SetRGBColorFill(m_Color.R, m_Color.G,
                                                    m_Color.B);
        // this is to set the cursor  tp Bottom Middle 
        int yPos = 0;
        yPos = PDFLayout.BottomHeight;
        pdfPageContents.SetTextMatrix(pageSize.Width / 2, yPos);

        pdfPageContents.ShowText(f_textPrefix.Trim());

        pdfPageContents.EndText();
    }
    pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true; // enable this if you want the PDF flattened. 
    pdfStamper.Close();              // Always close the stamper or you'll have a 0 byte stream. 
    byte []bt = btmemoryStream.ToArray();

    File.WriteAllBytes("C:\new_file.pdf", bt);
}
```

I've also attached the output of pdf screenshot, Please see the screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: PDFLayout.BottomHeight = 0
p_objParam.pdfBatesDetail.FontSize = 5.0;

these are just user_defined object have some values, please consider these values

Comment: I don't understand your problem. You choose the **y** coordinate. If you choose it so low that text is cut off, why don't you choose a larger value?

Comment: you can add a margin to the bottom of the page, but I think you have to build a template in order to do that (that's how I did it anyway)

Comment: @AlanVrog Does any of the answers answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

You have chosen to draw the text using a very low-level part of the iText API which essentially represents the exact text drawing instructions used inside the PDF.

These drawing instructions do not use the **y** coordinate you give as the *bottom* of the text but as the *base line*:

[image: g glyph bounding box with base line]

The line the glyph origins are on is the base line.

Thus, if you use the **y** coordinate of the bottom of the page for text drawing, the parts of the glyphs below the base line will be cut off.

---

To prevent this you can query your `BaseFont` instance how low bounding boxes in a string you want to draw can be using

```
/**
 * Gets the descent of a <CODE>String</CODE> in points. The descent will always be
 * less than or equal to zero even if all the characters have an higher descent.
 * @param text the <CODE>String</CODE> to get the descent of
 * @param fontSize the size of the font
 * @return the dexcent in points
 */
virtual public float GetDescentPoint(String text, float fontSize)
```

and subtract that value from your y coordinate.

Or you can use higher level API alternatives, some of them allow you to define a box inside which the text is drawn.

---

Another issue might be that you assume the bottom of the page to be at **y** coordinate 0. While this is often the case, it is not necessarily so. Thus, you might want to take the bottom of the crop box of the page in question into account.

Answer (score 1):

So, first thing first, I don't know iTextSharp well, I just used it once and I remember having the same problem. Here's what worked for me, and maybe this can help you too:

I have the following extension class:

```
public class ITextSharpExtension
{
//Add pagination
public class PageEventHelper : PdfPageEventHelper
{
    PdfContentByte cb;
    PdfTemplate template;


    public override void OnOpenDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        cb = writer.DirectContent;
        template = cb.CreateTemplate(50, 50);
    }

    public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        Font arial = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 10, GrayColor.GRAY);
        base.OnEndPage(writer, document);
        int pageN = writer.PageNumber;
        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
        string text = String.Format("Page {0} of ", pageN.ToString());
        float len = bf.GetWidthPoint(text, 8);

        iTextSharp.text.Rectangle pageSize = document.PageSize;

        cb.SetRGBColorFill(100, 100, 100);

        cb.BeginText();
        cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 10);
        cb.SetTextMatrix(10, pageSize.GetBottom(10));
        cb.ShowText(text);

        cb.EndText();

        cb.AddTemplate(template, 60, pageSize.GetBottom(10));
    }

    public override void OnCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        base.OnCloseDocument(writer, document);
        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
        template.BeginText();
        template.SetFontAndSize(bf, 10);
        template.SetTextMatrix(0, 0);
        template.ShowText("" + (writer.PageNumber - 1));
        template.EndText();
    }
}
```

}

And this line is where it adds the margin on the bottom:
`cb.AddTemplate(template, 60, pageSize.GetBottom(10));`  specifically this part: `pageSize.GetBottom(10)`